# Html class event listener is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

I have a class named "banner_category" with multiple ids as follows

```
  <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="banner_item align-items-center" id="cat1" style="background-image:url(images/bolts.jpg)">
                    <div class="banner_category">
                        <a href="#">Bolts</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="banner_item align-items-center" id="cat2" style="background-image:url(images/abrasives.jpg)">
                    <div class="banner_category">
                        <a href="#">Abrasives</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="banner_item align-items-center" id="cat3" style="background-image:url(images/valves.jpg)">
                    <div class="banner_category">
                        <a href="#">Valves</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="banner_item align-items-center" id="cat4" style="background-image:url(images/electrical.jpg)">
                    <div class="banner_category">
                        <a href="#>other</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What I want to do is when I click on each of the banner I want to get the banner text. For example when I click on id=cat4 it should console.log "other", id=cat1 should console.log "bolts"
I know how to setup event listener by the ids what I want to do is setup one function instead of four functions so I tried this

```
$(".banner_category").on("click", function(){
    var clickedcat = document.getElementById('cat').textContent;
    console.log(clickedcat);
})
```

but it only console.log the Bolts regardless on which one I click.

**How can I implement getting the respective text for each Id with one function?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an element with `cat` as id. There's no magic autocomplete for ids - you have to name the id you want to target.

That being said, first - don't mix jQuery and plain js - and second why don't you just output `$(this).text()`:

```
$(".banner_category").on("click", function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
    // optional - trim the text: $(this).text().trim()
});
```

```js
$('.banner_category').on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).text().trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="banner_item align-items-center" id="cat1" style="background-image:url(images/bolts.jpg)">
      <div class="banner_category">
        <a href="#">Bolts</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="banner_item align-items-center" id="cat2" style="background-image:url(images/abrasives.jpg)">
      <div class="banner_category">
        <a href="#">Abrasives</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="banner_item align-items-center" id="cat3" style="background-image:url(images/valves.jpg)">
      <div class="banner_category">
        <a href="#">Valves</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```